# Как передавать дату с временной зоной при помощи json?

Tags: java, время, jackson

Есть класс который содержит дату/время и временную зону:

```
public class TimeWrapper {

    private final Instant time;

    private final ZoneId zoneId;

    public TimeWrapper(long millisecondTime, String zone) {
        time = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisecondTime);
        time.atZone(zoneId = ZoneId.of(zone));
    }
}
```

Мне надо передать его при помощи `json` на клиент:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(new TimeWrapper(...));
System.out.println(json);
```

И тут получается что в `json` переводятся все внутренности этого классов  `ZoneId` и `Instant` которых как оказалось очень много. И которые мне совершенно не нужны.

Можно ли как то отсечь только мои время дату и временную зону, а остальное в `json` не писать, а то там несколько сотен строк. Или надо просто взять другой класс `Timestamp` на пример, а этот оставить?
Просто этот пакет time вроде как новый стандарт а что-то не очень удобно или я еще не умею его готовить? Подскажите как мне `json` передачу организовать так что бы тонну мусора не таскать за одно?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8 если Instant из java 8, https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda если Instant из Joda Time. Вместе с тем должен предупредить, что при десериализации Instant java 8 [были проблемы при указании временной зоны](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-datatype-jsr310/issues/79), когда этим занимался, просто плюнул и присылал все в дефолтной таймзоне (Z), т.к. проект не требовал ее хранения.

Comment: @etki ок спасибо я тогда не буду мучатся и просто обертку на Timestamp c String полем и буду там зону хранить